# autocomplete problems with serverside json

Tags: asp.net, jquery, json, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

For some reason the script below is not working.

This is the code I am using to generate the json data:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Response.Clear()
    Response.Write(generate_json_data())
    Response.End()
End Sub
```

This produces the following output on screen:

```
[ {id:0,value:"c++"}, {id:1,value:"java"}, {id:2,value:"php"}, {id:3,value:"coldfusion"}, {id:4,value:"javascript"}, {id:5,value:"asp"}, {id:6,value:"ruby"} ];
```

This is the jquery I have so far, which does not seem to work.  It does not give an error, when I type into the input field, nothing happens, when it should be displaying some of the data from the json data.

```
$("input").autocomplete({
    source: "serverside_array.aspx",
    dataType: "json",
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#txtAllowSearch").val(ui.item.value); // display the selected text
        $("#txtAllowSearchID").val(ui.item.id); // save selected id to hidden input
    }
});
```

EDIT 1: The header from the developer tools in chromium 10

```
Request URL:http://intranet/test_array.aspx?term=j
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headers
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host:intranet
Referer:http://intranet/rights_stage_three.aspx
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/10.0.652.0 Safari/534.17
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Query String Parameters
term:j
Response Headers
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:204
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 27 Jan 2011 16:11:14 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-AspNet-Version:2.0.50727
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

EDIT 2: looking at the reponse data XHR, I get the following

> name test_array.aspx
>
> method get
>
> status 200 ok
>
> type application/json
>
> size 204b
>
> time pending

EDIT 3:

Now I am totally confused.  I got it working by simply changing the contenttype generated by the aspx page to:

```
text/xml
```

instead of

```
applicaiton/json
```

why does it work with text/xml when I am returning json?

Comment: why not use a webservice such as an asmx to generate the json?

Comment: Is that why I am experiencing problems? Because I am not using a webservice to generate the json?

Comment: well, writing to the .aspx it unconventional for this - this is why the .asmx is used. Some background on asmx I have answered before on setting those up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225781/asp-net-web-method-that-accepts-a-listcustomobject-is-failing-with-web-service/2268178#2268178

Comment: here is and MVC example: http://blog.schuager.com/2008/09/jquery-autocomplete-json-apsnet-mvc.html

Comment: Please have a look at edit 3 in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a webdev tool like Firebug or Operas and Chromes built-in dev-tools which can list HTTP requests and responses to you.

Check if a JavaScript error is logged.

If not, check for the response, and that the responses Content-Type is `text/javascript` if it’s a callback, or `application/json` if only JSON data.

Without the content type the ajax request may fail because of security against XSS.

Comment: Using the developer tools in chromium 10, it does not seem to display and javascript error messages.  However, it reports that it has successfully retrieve html when I type something into the input field, when I would have thought it should be reporting the retrieval of json...

Comment: I have updated my original post to include details on the header and the reponse XHR.

Answer (score 1):

```
[ {id:0,value:"c++"}, {id:1,value:"java"}, {id:2,value:"php"}, {id:3,value:"coldfusion"}, {id:4,value:"javascript"}, {id:5,value:"asp"}, {id:6,value:"ruby"} ];
```

The semicolon at the end of the string should not be there. Also the Content-Type of the response should be `application/json`. And consider to put all values in double quotes. May be it will work without it, but it is not the proper JSON format without it. This is the standard compliant JSON string:

```
[{"id":0,"value":"c++"}, {"id":1,"value":"java"}, {"id":2,"value":"php"}]
```